# How to access a JSON array with params in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

For my API in RAILS I would like to access a JSON array for some operations and save it in an array.

Something like this: JSON `[{"consumption":2.3e-06,"date":"00:15"},{"consumption":1.3e-06,"date":"00:30"}]`

This JSON is sent from `curl` and in the controller i want to do something like this:

```
a[0] = params[0][:consumption]
```

Here 0 should be different(0,1,2...) to access the different positions in my JSON array. (1 consumption, 2 consumption and so on)

But I dont know how to do manage this with `params`

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you will not be able to access this JSON array in way you expect(`params[0]`).

first - `params` object is a wrapper on data sent to server (it also keeps current controller/action name). You have to wrap your JSON array in a param of name you would like to access it on server. 
For example, you may POST your data and the payload may look: { consumption_data: array_from_your_post }.

Then this array will be accessible by invoking `params[:consumption_data]` in your controller. First item of array is then `params[:consumption_data][0]` and so on.

How to send your json via curl?

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"consumption_data": [here_put_your_items]}' http://localhost:3000/action_name
```

Comment: With your indications it worked. I really appreciate it.